# Script to generate an image on a tilemap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I am new to game development. I wanted to do a simple project, where upon clicking a button causes an image to be generated on a particular tile. I have created my 2D tilemap and buttons, but not very sure on how to create the script to perform the game logic. Could someone help?
I have tried writing the script and attaching it to the buttons but it doesn't work.
Thank you very much!

My code for the image generator for reference:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class ImageGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tilemap tilemap;
    public GameObject imagePrefab;

    public void GenerateImageOnTile(Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        Instantiate(imagePrefab, targetPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Tile script:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Color _baseColor, _offsetColor;
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _renderer;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _highlight;
    public event Action<Tile> OnButtonClick; /

    public void Init(bool isOffset)
    {
        _renderer.color = isOffset ? _offsetColor : _baseColor;
    }

    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        _highlight.SetActive(true);
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        _highlight.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void OnButtonClicked()
    {
        OnButtonClick?.Invoke(this); 
    }
}
```

The grid manager script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridManager : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private int _width, _height;
    [SerializeField] private Tile _tilePrefab;
    [SerializeField] private ImageGenerator _imageGenerator;

    void Start() {
        GenerateGrid();
    }

    void GenerateGrid() { 
        for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < _height; y++) {
                var spawnedTile = Instantiate(_tilePrefab, new Vector3(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
                spawnedTile.Init((x + y) % 2 == 0);

              
                spawnedTile.OnButtonClick += GenerateFlower;

                spawnedTile.name = $"Tile {x} {y}";
            }
        }
    }

    private void GenerateImage(Tile clickedTile)
    {
        _imageGenerator.GenerateImageOnTile(clickedTile.transform.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've got? It would make it much easier to understand where you're coming from.

Comment: Hi, I've posted it

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with UnityEngine.Tilemaps, you can use the method included in the tilemap to get and set the tile.

It would look something like this:

```
tilemap.SetTile( _targetPosition, _tilePrefab);
```

If you want to create your own grid on top of the tilemap, there are also some handy get methods like: tilemap.CellToWorld, tilemap.WorldToCell and tilemap.cellSize.

Here's the links to the document:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.html

Also would like to mention about your code:

```
var spawnedTile = Instantiate(...);          
spawnedTile.OnButtonClick += GenerateFlower;
```

If you want to subscribe to the event in your custom Tile class, you might want to write it more explicit, otherwise I think it will only return the gameObject.

```
Tile spawnedTile = Instantiate(...).GetComponent<Tile>();          
spawnedTile.OnButtonClick += GenerateFlower;
```

Also the logic seems a bit weird here because normally I will do the subscribe code inside the OnEnable() so i can unsubscribe it in the OnDisable(). So you might want to give more explainations to why are you want to do it this way.